# Convert projection Toolbox ArcMap 10.2

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2

I'm having trouble with a toolbox based on a python script that converts the  projection of shapefiles. I want to choose a folder that contains my shp, convert them to wgs84 then put them in another folder:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Import arcpy module
import arcpy, sys
import os
from arcpy import env

# Script arguments
Folder_input = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
folder_output=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
Output_Coordinate_System = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

# Process: Project
arcpy.env.workspace= Folder_input
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
for infc in acrpy.ListFeatureClasses():
     Output_Dataset_or_Feature_Class=os.path.join(folder_output, infc)
     arcpy.Project_management(infc, Output_Dataset_or_Feature_Class,Output_Coordinate_System, "", "")
     arcpy.env.scratchWorkspace = tempEnvironment0
```

I have this error

> ERROR : NameError: name 'acrpy' is not defined
>
> Failed to execute (Script).

Comment: Seriously?  "Acrpy"??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
for infc in acrpy.ListFeatureClasses():
```

`acrpy` should be `arcpy`

Correcting the typo should eliminate that error.

Comment: Thank you, I corrected the error but my script failed when my folder contains more than one shape file, it convert the projection of one shp then gives this message : Not defined

Comment: @Hchliyah is that the entire error?  If it's different to the previous `acrpy` error it might be worth asking a separate question

Comment: Yes it's the entire error